# How to determine what is causing catastrophic error

Tags: vba

I am getting catastrophic error at certain sequence on listbox form selection...
how can I determine what exactly is causing catastrophic error? The error is repeatable from my file.

On bellow code I put msgbox "a" and error doesn't appear any more... If I remove that it will apear again. Also it appears only right after I run the excel file and open forms and select item on that listbox.
Also the code is around 4000 lines and 150000 characters for this specific form. With other classes it's over 10000 lines and over 300000 characters.

```
Private Sub ListBox3_Change()
Dim partf As Variant, ctype As String
ReDim fncleft(4)
ReDim fncright(4)
Dim i As Integer, h As Integer
For i = 0 To Me.ListBox3.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListBox3.Selected(i) = True Then
        With bomfix.ExcelTables(Me.ComboBox_Tables2.Value).settings
            If Me.ListBox3.List(i, 1) <> vbNullString Then
                Me.CheckBox_SQLltrim.Enabled = True
                Me.CheckBox_SQLrtrim.Enabled = True
                Me.CheckBox_SQLtrim.Enabled = True
                Me.CheckBox_SQLlower.Enabled = True
                Me.CheckBox_SQLupper.Enabled = True
                Me.CommandButtonSQLreplace.Enabled = True
                Me.Frame9.Visible = True
                Me.TextBox_ConstraintType.Visible = True
                Me.CommandButton8.Visible = True
                Me.Label99.Visible = True
                Me.Label100.Visible = True
                Me.TextBox_ConstrTableName.Visible = True
                Me.TextBox_ConstrColumnName.Visible = True
                If .TableExists(Me.ListBox3.List(i, 0)) = True Then
                    If .Table(Me.ListBox3.List(i, 0)).ColumnExists(Me.ListBox3.List(i, 1)) = True Then
                        Me.ComboBox_PartTable.List = .Tables
                        Me.ComboBox_PartTable.AddItem vbNullString, 0
                        With .Table(Me.ListBox3.List(i, 0))
                            Me.CheckBox_FullJoinTable.Enabled = True
                            Me.CheckBox_FullJoinTable.Value = .FullJoin
                            With .column(Me.ListBox3.List(i, 1))
                                Me.TextBox_ExportName.Value = .Value
                                Me.CheckBox_ColumnHidden.Value = .Hidden
                                Me.CheckBox_ColumnEnabled.Value = .Active
                                Me.TextBox_ConstraintType.Value = .ConstraintType
                                Me.TextBox_ConstrTableName.Value = .ConstraintTable
                                Me.TextBox_ConstrColumnName.Value = .ConstraintColumn
                                Me.CheckBox_SQLltrim.Value = .SQLltrim
                                Me.CheckBox_SQLrtrim.Value = .SQLrtrim
                                Me.CheckBox_SQLtrim.Value = .SQLtrim
                                Me.CheckBox_SQLlower.Value = .SQLlower
                                Me.CheckBox_SQLupper.Value = .SQLupper
                                MsgBox "b"
                                partf = .PartitionFilter
                                If Not UBound(partf) < 0 Then
                                    Me.TextBox_PartResults.Value = partf(0)
                                    If bomfix.ExcelTables(Me.ComboBox_Tables2.Value).settings.TableExists(partf(1)) = True Then
                                        Me.ComboBox_PartTable.Value = partf(1)
                                        Me.ComboBox_PartColumn.List = bomfix.ExcelTables(Me.ComboBox_Tables2.Value).settings.Table(Me.ComboBox_PartTable.Value).Columns
                                        Me.ComboBox_PartColumn.AddItem vbNullString, 0
                                        If bomfix.ExcelTables(Me.ComboBox_Tables2.Value).settings.Table(partf(1)).ColumnExists(partf(2)) = True Then
                                            Me.ComboBox_PartColumn.Value = partf(2)
                                            Me.ComboBox_PartOrderBy.Value = partf(3)
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                Else
                                    Me.TextBox_PartResults.Value = vbNullString
                                    Me.ComboBox_PartTable.Value = vbNullString
                                    Me.ComboBox_PartColumn.Value = vbNullString
                                    Me.ComboBox_PartOrderBy.Value = vbNullString
                                End If
                                Me.TextBox_FuncLeftCol.Value = Me.ListBox3.List(i, 0) & "." & Me.ListBox3.List(i, 1)
                                Me.ComboBox_FuncRightVal.Value = Me.ComboBox_FuncRightVal.List(0)
                                ' add filters  Array(and_or, Comparator, tableright, columnright, FunctionRight, FunctionLeft)
                                Me.ListBox4.Clear
                                For h = 1 To .FilterSet.Count
                                    Me.ListBox4.AddItem
                                    Me.ListBox4.List(Me.ListBox4.ListCount - 1, 0) = .FilterSet(h)(0) ' and_or
                                    Me.ListBox4.List(Me.ListBox4.ListCount - 1, 1) = Join(.FilterSet(h)(5), "|") ' function left
                                    Me.ListBox4.List(Me.ListBox4.ListCount - 1, 2) = .FilterSet(h)(1) ' comparator
                                    Me.ListBox4.List(Me.ListBox4.ListCount - 1, 3) = .FilterSet(h)(2) ' table right
                                    Me.ListBox4.List(Me.ListBox4.ListCount - 1, 4) = .FilterSet(h)(3) ' column right
                                    Me.ListBox4.List(Me.ListBox4.ListCount - 1, 5) = Join(.FilterSet(h)(4), "|") ' function right
                                Next
                            End With
                        End With
                    End If
                End If
            ElseIf Me.ListBox3.List(i, 2) <> vbNullString Then
                If .Aggregates.Exists(Me.ListBox3.List(i, 0)) = True Then
                    With .Aggregates(Me.ListBox3.List(i, 0))(1)
                        Me.CheckBox_SQLltrim.Enabled = False
                        Me.CheckBox_SQLrtrim.Enabled = False
                        Me.CheckBox_SQLtrim.Enabled = False
                        Me.CheckBox_SQLlower.Enabled = False
                        Me.CheckBox_SQLupper.Enabled = False
                        Me.CommandButtonSQLreplace.Enabled = False
                        Me.CheckBox_FullJoinTable.Enabled = False
                        Me.Frame9.Visible = False
                        Me.TextBox_ConstraintType.Visible = False
                        Me.CommandButton8.Visible = False
                        Me.Label99.Visible = False
                        Me.Label100.Visible = False
                        Me.TextBox_ConstrTableName.Visible = False
                        Me.TextBox_ConstrColumnName.Visible = False
                        Me.TextBox_ExportName.Value = .Value
                        Me.CheckBox_ColumnHidden.Value = .Hidden
                        Me.CheckBox_ColumnEnabled.Value = .Active
                        Me.TextBox_ConstraintType.Value = .ConstraintType
                        Me.TextBox_ConstrTableName.Value = .ConstraintTable
                        Me.TextBox_ConstrColumnName.Value = .ConstraintColumn
                        Me.TextBox_FuncLeftCol.Value = "aggregate"
                        Me.ComboBox_FuncRightVal.Value = Me.ComboBox_FuncRightVal.List(0)
                        ' add filters  Array(and_or, Comparator, tableright, columnright, FunctionRight, FunctionLeft)
                        Me.ListBox4.Clear
                        For h = 1 To .FilterSet.Count
                            Me.ListBox4.AddItem
                            Me.ListBox4.List(Me.ListBox4.ListCount - 1, 0) = .FilterSet(h)(0)
                            Me.ListBox4.List(Me.ListBox4.ListCount - 1, 1) = Join(.FilterSet(h)(5), "|")
                            Me.ListBox4.List(Me.ListBox4.ListCount - 1, 2) = .FilterSet(h)(1)
                            Me.ListBox4.List(Me.ListBox4.ListCount - 1, 3) = .FilterSet(h)(2)
                            Me.ListBox4.List(Me.ListBox4.ListCount - 1, 4) = .FilterSet(h)(3)
                            Me.ListBox4.List(Me.ListBox4.ListCount - 1, 5) = Join(.FilterSet(h)(4), "|")
                        Next
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        End With
        Exit For
    End If
Next
Me.ComboBox_FuncTypeRight.Value = Me.ComboBox_FuncTypeRight.List(0)
Me.ComboBox_FuncTypeLeft.Value = Me.ComboBox_FuncTypeLeft.List(0)
Call ComboBox_FuncComp_Change
```

End Sub

Comment: *With other classes it's over 10000 lines* - a VBA module can't exceed 10K lines (number of characters is irrelevant, but the compiled P-Code must not exceed 64KB). You need to break things down into smaller, more specialized procedures. A procedure shouldn't ever need to be any taller than a single screen, and the vast majority of procedure scopes don't need to be any larger than a dozen lines of code, if not just a handful. If the project compiles (>10K lines in a module wouldn't), the catastrophic error is likely related to that. You need to refactor/extract methods, urgently! =)

Comment: Sorry, correction: it's not a module, but a *procedure* that can't exceed 10K lines (you get "Procedure too long" compile error)

Comment: Does 10k lines comply just to a module or all classes used within the module? Does this include code for forms? I get no procedure errors... Excel file just gets corrupted and it creates duplicates of sheets and workbooks.

Comment: VB Debug says this: Exception thrown at 0x000007FED0052312 (VBE7.DLL) in EXCEL.EXE: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000012831000.

Comment: Your host document is corrupted. I would export the code to some folder, and then re-create the workbook from scratch.

Comment: Does that mean recreating all the forms by hand?

Comment: I think I know what you mean. There are some event handlers hidden that are not visible in VBA unlike vb.net... I assume some didn't get erased while deleting stuff etc and got left in a file. Anyway I commented out `Call ComboBox_FuncComp_Change` and the problem dissapeared for now. That combobox change called change on further comboboxes...

Comment: Event handler procedures should be invoked by the MSForms controls, not by user code - as I said you have a massive refactoring journey ahead of you. On the bright side, you'll learn a ton of things about programming user interfaces if you do this right. Your form is running the show, and it absolutely should not be. It running the show is why you're looking at massively bloated code-behind. Good luck!